# MigraDoc Rotate Image (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, migradoc

I am trying to create a PDF using MigraDoc Library. I can add an image, but unable to rotate images. I am creating a MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image object to add the image to a section. Is it possible to rotate the image or do I have to add the image another way?

```
Public Sub AddImageToPDFFile(sec As Section)
    Dim image As Image
    Dim strImagePath = "image.jpg"
    image = sec.AddImage(strImagePath)
    image.Height = "10cm"
    image.LockAspectRatio = True
    image.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line
    image.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin
    image.Top = ShapePosition.Top
    image.Left = ShapePosition.Left
    image.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid MigraDoc cannot rotate the image.

Maybe rotate the image with code before adding it to MigraDoc.

It might also be possible, depending on your requirements, to add the image later using PDFsharp. MigraDoc uses PDFsharp to create the PDF and thus you can use PDFsharp for modifications without adding an additional tool to the process.